Water Copper type M tubing in Illinois
I have house from 2007. While updating the bathroom I noticed they used type M copper tubing on 1/2 and 3/4 water supply lines. It seems code doesn't allow that in Illinois. Shall I be worried about the fact that I have weak water pipes? How long will they last?

Code changes, so you need to check 2007 code to see if it was in code or not.  The same goes with your electrical system, it was in code in 2007 and will be grandfathered today, but a few circuits will not be allowed to be installed as was, today

Likewise, test your water. Even a cheap pH strip test will tell you the most important factor with regard to rotting out copper pipes, which is whether it's acidic (below 7.0) or not. A more complete test may be worthwhile if you have not done one, or may be available free for the looking if you are on municipal water.

Type M CWT is standard for residential water supply piping in many locations. So if you feel the need to be worried, you have lots of company. The durabilty of copper tubing seems to be greatly dependent on the particular chemical properties of the water at a specific location. I know of several such installations over 50 years old where I live (Seattle).
